# Finding $a,b,c,d$ in a complicated expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help finding integer solutions to $a,b,c,d$ in the equation$$b^2+936102017=a^2+334535297=c^2+325018082=d^2+945619232$$Any ideas? I'm not sure how to input something like this into Mathematica, and I'm sure as hell not going to calculate that by hand.

This is not for homework, in case you were wondering.

Comment: integer solution of $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: @MANMAID Yes, I'll add that in.

Comment: $945619232-936102017=334535297-325018082=9517215=3 \times 5 \times 89 \times 7129$

Answer (score 1):

HInt:$$b^2+936102017=a^2+334535297 \to \\
a^2-b^2=601566720\to \\(a-b)(a+b)=601566720\\(a-b)(a+b)=2^7\times 3\times 5\times 29\times 37\times 73$$ then you can do for other equations , and check all those possibilities .$$
\begin{cases}a^2-b^2=601566720\\c^2-a^2=334535297-325018082 \\d^2-c^2=945619232-325018082\\\vdots
\end{cases}$$ you will have $6$ equation to solve ...$\left(\begin{array}{c}4\\ 2\end{array}\right)=6$

Comment: well, this way it might take a long time...

Comment: @MANMAID :Are you looking for a tricky way ...,Do it by programming .Rapid and reliable solution.